# Normal distributed $\log x$

Tags: statistics, logarithms, normal-distribution

Assuming $\log x$ is normally distributed. How do I get the distribution of $x$? Also how can I get the standard deviation of $x$ assuming I know some asymmetric error on $x$ like e.g. Table 1 in https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aad90c/pdf

Comment: Hi @Aeronestes, you may use $\LaTeX$ to enhance your problem.

Comment: Find CDF of $x$ on base of $x\leq a\iff\log(x)\leq\log(a)$ for positive $a$. Its derivative is the PDF of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y:=\ln X$ has CDF $F_Y$, $X$ has CDF $F_X(x):=P(X\le x)=P(Y\le\ln x)=F_Y(\ln x)$, so its PDF is $f_X(x):=\frac{d}{dx}F_X(x)=\tfrac1xF_Y^\prime(\ln X)$ by the chain rule. In terms of $Y$'s PDF $f_Y:=F_Y^\prime$, $f_X(x):=\tfrac1xf_Y(\ln x)$. This gives the distribution discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Probability_density_function).

Answer (score 0):

If

$$Y=\log X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$$

Then

$$X\sim \text{Log-Normal}$$

to find the pdf of $X$ simply use the fundamental transformation theorem (EDIT) that is the following

$$f_X(x)=f_Y(g^{-1}(x))|\frac{d}{dx}g^ {-1 }(y)|$$

Where $Y=g^{-1}(X)=\log X$

Thus

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\log x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$$

$x >0$

Here read more on [Log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

Comment: Although I'm sure I know which "fundamental transformation theorem" you mean, I get nothing useful when Googling it. Your answer would be more helpful if it stated or linked to said theorem.

Comment: @J.G. Answer edited including the theorem I mean